# HTML5 Background Video/MP4 not playing in Chrome/Firefox touchscreen laptops

Tags: wordpress, html, video, background

I have a Wordpress website in development at http://comdoc.wpengine.com, and I am noticing that the background video for my top section is not playing in Chrome or Firefox on touchscreen laptops. My understanding is that this is because they are being detected as mobile devices, thus blocking the video.

Currently, I am using Revolution Slider to make it work, but I'd like to avoid the bulk when all I need is the video.

The example can be found at http://comdoc.wpengine.com. I have two sections, the first being Revolution Slider, and the second being just HTML 5 with the theme's (X / Cornerstone) built-in classes.

Answer (score 0):

try to update Slider Revolution plugin, they fix this issue in 5.4.8 version